# How to show an UIView on top of an UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UIViewController` which contains a table view and a simple view. Both of them are at the same level.

At startup my view starts hidden at the bottom and when I press a button I want my view to slide up. When I do this only 1/4 of the view is shown and not the complete view.

This worked okay before adding the table view, but now I don't understand why it doesn't fully show.

Here is the code to show and hide my view:

```
func showPicker(date: Date?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.timePickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}

func hidePicker() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.timePickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.timePickerView.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}
```

And here is a screenshot with the view (below the buttons there should be an `UIDatePicker` which is not shown):

[image]

Someone know what the issue is ? I am trying to do this from the storyboards.

edit:

This is what I have right now, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't animate and it also shows just a part of the view. Apparently if I increase the height the view is shown even more, so somehow it says that the shown part is exactly 220 height, which is strange :/

```
func hidePicker() {
   self.pickerBottomConstraint.constant = -220
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.timePickerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}

func showPicker(date: Date?) {
    self.pickerBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.timePickerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

    })
}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Cuase if you do, just toggle the constraint value of your picker and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using autolayout, I bet you do and you should, then the easiest way to do what you wanna do is to toggle the constraint of your view, see the gif I added below.

First is to have a reference to your either top or bottom constraint of your view you wanna show and hide. Then modify the constant of the constraint to adjust its position, in that way, you get the illusion that the view is hidden and shown. The demo below uses tableView too.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I can't seem to manage to make it work. I added IB outlet to bottom constraint and now instead of using a transform operation I just change the bottom constraint to 0 if show and -220 (height of view) when hide.  Is that correct ? It's still showing only 1/4 of it and there is no animation

Comment: you should call layoutIfNeeded after changing constraint value for animation. You should also have height constraint (If not.).

Comment: @Mukesh: I have an height constraint. I also used layoutIfNeeded. Still doesn't work, I updated my question with my current code.

Comment: @Kobe, you can use the generic animation code. You only call `layoutIfNeeded()` after changing the constraint value. Check out @Sh_Khan's sample. I will update my answer with some pieces of codes later.

Answer (score 2):

See a demo here [showHide](https://github.com/ShKhan9/showHide/tree/master/showHide) that accomplish what you want

[image]

Comment: I am using bottom constraint because I don't have any top one, but it doesn't work, I don't understand how for you it animates, for me it doesn't animate at all, very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then transform, change your views center y position.
ex:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewToAnimateOutlet: UIView!
@IBAction func showViewButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
        self.viewToAnimateOutlet.center.y -= self.viewToAnimateOutlet.frame.height
    }
        }
@IBAction func hideViewButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
        self.viewToAnimateOutlet.center.y += self.viewToAnimateOutlet.frame.height
    }
}
```

What i did:
I used autolayout and provided constraint for ViewToAnimate View is

#### ViewToAnimates.leading = safeArea.leading "constant = 8"

#### ViewToAnimates.trailing = safeArea.trailing "constant = 8"

> This constraint will place ViewToAnimate view outside of the main views bottom. so view will not visible until showViewButtonAction method called.
>
> #### ViewToAnimates.top = safeArea.bottom "constant = 0"

#### ViewToAnimates.height = 130

[image: View is now out of screen]

[image: View is now visible]