# Swift - How to show UIView from Bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a Android Developer and I'm starting to develop in `Swift` now. I want to know how to do to show a `UIView` from bottom, something like this: [image]

By now I know how to do this, but using the bottom view as a `UIViewController`, I saw this on a Stackoverflow answer someday. https://github.com/luangs7/BottomDialogSwift

Well, to sum up, I just need to show a `UIView`, with a custom `xib`, from bottom with a custom `height`.

Comment: unclear? really?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing some animation stuff. If you are using storyboard then provide constraint for your view like this,

> ViewToAnimates.leading = safeArea.leading "constant = 0"
>   ViewToAnimates.trailing = safeArea.trailing "constant = 0"
>   ViewToAnimates.top = safeArea.bottom "constant = 0"(Your view will be placed below ViewControllers main View)

Now show your view like this,

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewToAnimateOutlet: UIView!
@IBAction func showViewButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
    self.viewToAnimateOutlet.center.y -= self.viewToAnimateOutlet.frame.height
   }
}
@IBAction func hideViewButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
    self.viewToAnimateOutlet.center.y += self.viewToAnimateOutlet.frame.height
   }
}
```

[See this question and answeres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600133/4644528)

Answer (score 1):

The picture you are showing of what you want, the modal on top of the other view, can be done using a custom animation.

You can set the property on the UIViewController being presented on screen that is called `.transitioningDelegate` and make the UIViewController already on screen the delegate.  And in the methods that you implement on the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` you need to return a custom instance of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

You can subclass `NSObject and have it adhere to the protocols of`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`. In that object you can control the custom size of the view that is on top of the others, the position on screen, as well as how to animate it. And if you want to put any other views in between that view and the other views on screen, such as a grey semi-transparent view.

You do that all in the method:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
 //here is where you do your magic custom animation
}

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    //set the duration of the animation here
}
```

To make this work, setup your modal view as any other member of your storyboard and link to it from the `UIViewController` that you want it to animate on top of using a `segue`.

Then in that `UIViewController` method

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if let vc = segue.destination as? MyCustomModalView {

            vc.transitioningDelegate = self
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

        }
 }
```

Reference that view and set the transitioningDelegate as self, (or some other object)

There are a bunch of tutorials on the internet that walk you through this process, it’s not that difficult once you understand the flow

I would start with the Ray wenderlich one [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173576/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-3)

Comment: Oh thank you. I have found some tutorials, but no one clear to me. I'll take a look at this one. Thanks